# See what will cascade delete before running the delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cascade

Is there a way with SQL Server to see what will be deleted before the actual delete is run?

Say I have a customer table that Foreign Keys to orders and addresses with cascading deletes.

If I delete a customer then SQL Server will delete all the orders and addresses for that customer too.

Is there a way to get the Primary keys for the tables that will have deletes done on them without running the actual delete statement?

**NOTE:** Obviously I could code a sproc by hand to do this for this specific example.  But my question is asking if the way SQL Server does it (for the delete) can be used to get info rather than just do the delete.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to:

1. start a transaction
2. run your deletion
3. select from tables
4. roll back your transaction